# Звуки в Python (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, аудио, библиотеки

Я делаю игру на **Python** с помощью библиотеки **tkinter**. Я хочу добавить в программу музыку на заднем фоне, и чтобы другой звук работал при нажатие на кнопку. Какие библиотеки для этого есть? И как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот:

```
from playsound import playsound 
playsound('ПУТЬ К ФАЙЛУ.mp3')
```

Но пока этот код выполняется пользователь не может нажимать на другие кнопки

Comment: Автор вопроса четко указал, что нужны нажатия на другие кнопки, пока играет музыка. Не является ответом

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, неправильный ответ - тоже ответ. Хотя и неправильный.

Answer (score 1):

Используя прошлый ответ, можно сделать так:

Музыка запускается через функцию, функция открывается в отдельном потоке:

```
from threading import Thread
from playsound import playsound 

def music():playsound('ПУТЬ К ФАЙЛУ.mp3')#функция которая будет играть музыка

Thread(target = music, daemon=True).start()#запускается функция в отдельном потоке
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pygame import mixer


mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('путь/к/музыке.mp3')

mixer.music.play()
```

Для того, чтобы музыка играла бесконечно, пишите так:

```py
mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Лично у меня в `Pydroid 3` при выполнении этого кода можно взаимодействовать с интерфейсом.